# MGLMapView - Mapbox annotations crash

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, exc-bad-access, mglmapview

I have crashes in Crashlytics tool and I don't know how to fix them. Screenshot of how it looks in Crashlytics:

[image: Crashlytics screenshot]

It seems that problem is in Mapbox source codes. Codes from my project:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
   let annotsToRemove = self?.mapView.annotations?.filter({ $0 is MapDangerAnnotation })
   let annotsToAdd = dangers.map { MapDangerAnnotation(danger: $0) }
```

84 line is middle line with filter function. I don't know what could be wrong. Do you know where could be problem? One thing I could think of is that I am not working in main thread but it's just working in most cases and crashing just in few cases.

Thanks, for help

Comment: Could you share which version of the Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS you are using?

Comment: Also, do you still see these crashes if you move the filter to the main thread? UI changes such as adding and removing annotations should occur on the main thread.

Comment: I was using 3.7.8 Mapbox version. Today I updated this version to newest 4.0.1 so I am looking forward to if this help or not. Problem is that I can't simulate this problem but I have it only from real users (not all, just part of them, probably in some situation, iOS 9 - 11) in Crashlytics. That's why It would be hard to test if moving this function to main thread helps but It would be the best thing to do.